# Android: Monitoring Bluetooth Discovery - what does this compile error mean?

Tags: android

I'm learning Bluetooth programming on Android using the Wrox *Professional Android 2 Application Development* book.  The discovery monitor example (pg 432) has this code snippet:

```
    BroadcastReceiver discoveryMonitor = new BroadcastReceiver() {

          String dStarted = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED;
          String dFinished = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED;

          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (dStarted.equals(intent.getAction())) { 
              // Discovery has started.
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             "Discovery Started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (dFinished.equals(intent.getAction())) {
              // Discovery has completed.
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             "Discovery Completed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }      
        };
        registerReceiver(discoveryMonitor, 
                         new IntentFilter(dStarted));
        registerReceiver(discoveryMonitor, 
                         new IntentFilter(dFinished));
```

... and on each of the two registerReceiver calls at the end I get . . .

**Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead

Syntax error, insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList**

What's an annotationName and what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you defined variables `dStarted` and `dFinished` as locals for `discoveryMonitor` BroadcastReceiver,
That way, you can't use them in registerReceiver(...)

You have to define them as global, or use

```
registerReceiver(discoveryMonitor, new 
                 IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
```

instead.