# Return type for the method is missing in registerReceiver

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am doing the basic tutorial for bluetooth [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

My code so far is

```
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivityBlueTooth extends Activity {

    //private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter ;    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_blue_tooth);

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }


        /*if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }*/

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }

    }



    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };



    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy


}
```

Eclipse is giving me a **Return type for the method is missing** error in registerReceiver. Could you give me a hint of what I am doing wrong here? Am I supposed to  register my receiver in my onResume method? Sorry for asking something so trivial but I could not find the answer is StackOverflow.

I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092151/registerreceiver-getting-passed-clicklistener) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146402/android-monitoring-bluetooth-discovery-what-does-this-compile-error-mean) with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you error because you have defined it outside the method. Your code

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
```

is not inside any method, Just create a onResume() method like below and move your code in it.

```
@Override 
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
}
```

Comment: I suspected that this was the reason .Thank you Kedarnath

Comment: The system didn't allow me to instantly accept the answer.There you go

Comment: @MikeVol yeah that's time. Thanks.